# java regex reluctant quantifier giving greedy quantifier

Tags: java, regex

im trying out java regex quantifiers

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^s(.*?)n$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("sensation");
    if(m.matches()){
        System.out.println("dude how is this even possible");
        System.out.print(m.group() + m.start()+m.end()+"\n");



    }else {
        System.out.println("sorry dude someting wrong");
    }
```

since it was relecutant quantifier it was supposed to give the following result
sen
sation

but instead im getting sensation where does it went wrong or what did i missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've told the program *twice* that your pattern needs to match the entire string.  That's why it can't match just the `"sen"` part, even when you use a reluctant qualifier.

(1) The `$` at the end of the pattern matches the end of the string; it will not let you match `"sen"` because `"sen"` isn't followed by the end of the string.

(2) You're using `m.matches()`, which only returns true if the entire string is matched.  See the definition of [`matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--).

Remove `$` and change `matches()` to `find()`.

Comment: thanks after changing   from matches to find i get the partial answer i.e   sen. whats the reason i didnt get the second result  sation

Comment: You output `m.group()`, which outputs the portion that you matched, which is `sen`.  You didn't output anything else that would output a different part of the input string.  Your original code outputs `m.start()` and `m.end()`, which are `int`s.  Did you see those in the output?  Anyway, if `s` is the input string, the part of the string following the match will be `s.substring(m.end())`.  This returns the portion of the input string starting at the character following the match, and going all the way to the end of the input string.

Comment: @javaworld: Regex engine can only find non-overlapping matches. It's possible to workaround and find overlapping matches which start at different positions (by using look-ahead), but it's not possible to find overlapping matches which start at the same position.